# cd /media/[user]/[external hdd]: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo, external-hdd, cd-command

I don't have permission to cd into my own external hard drive. `sudo cd` is not a syntactically legal command (tried it). What is going on?

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the output of `groups`?  It would be helpful to know if you're in the `media` group, specifically.

Comment: if gaining root permission is issue you can do sudo su[ENTER], give passwd and you will have permission. Also have you tried browsing cd from graphical file manager?

Comment: Try using `pmount` or mounting through Nautilus (`gvfs-mount`) so the media gets mounted with different ownership.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. For some reason there are two mount points in /media/[etc], [name of external] and [name of external]1. This also shows up in Nautilus. [name of external] doesn't lead anywhere, but all my files are on [name of external]1, both in Nautilus on in terminal, and I do have cd permission for that file path. It's strange, but technically not broken?

Comment: I got exactly the same issue...and thanks to your question and comment I solved it.